# How can I read supporting files by line in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, parsing

I'm currently making a web browsing program in Xcode 4.5.1 for OS X and I am trying to work on a list of bookmarks. What I hope to do is to have a supporting file called Bookmarks.txt in which I would list bookmarks like this:

```
Google
http://www.google.com/
Apple
http://www.apple.com/
Microsoft
http://www.microsoft.com/
```

I have already looked at a lot of pages discussing this, but none of them apply to what I'm doing. What I have now is

```
NSMutableArray *list;

NSString *contents;
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Bookmarks" ofType:@"txt"];
if (filePath) {
    content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    for (NSString *line in [contents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]) {
        [list addObject:line];
    }
}
```

as well as Dave DeLong's method, but I get all kinds of errors with Dave DeLong's and with this one nothing happens. Any help would be great, but I am just starting out at Xcode and know very little.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to initialise your array "list", surely! And "contents" is nil, too.

Comment: I would imagine saving it as a plist file would be much easier than as a txt file

Comment: Why not use a NSDictionary with bookmark name -> URL ? Off my head, you could load it with `-[NSDictionary initWithContentsOfFile:]` and save it with `-[NSDictionary writeToFile:atomically:]`.

Comment: How do u create a dictionary file?

Answer (score 0):

Your objects aren't initialized.

```
NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Bookmarks" ofType:@"txt"];
if (filePath) {
    NSString * content = [NSString initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    for (NSString *line in [contents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]) {
        [list addObject:line];
    }
}
```

Comment: It says initWithContentsOfFile doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry. Should be: 
`NSString * content = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];`